# Remove the characters in two strings if the character matches both the string

Tags: java, string

compare two strings and remove the same strings and store it in a new array

```
string1 = aabcdef
string2 = abcghi
the result should be final = adefghi
```

how can this be implemented

Comment: Start by specifying your needs better. Have you tried any implementation yourself, and how did that go?

Comment: I know what you want, give me a moment

Comment: Mathwog Check my post

Answer (score 0):

This eliminates all repeated characters in both strings

```
import java.util.HashSet;

class Rextester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String a = "aabcdef";
    String b = "abcghi";
    System.out.println(regenerate(a,b));
    //Thread.sleep(10000000);
}

public static String regenerate(String a, String b)
{
    HashSet<String> yaRetiradas = new HashSet<>();
    for(String letra : a.split("(?!^)")){
        if(!yaRetiradas.contains(letra) && b.contains(letra)){
            a = a.replaceFirst(letra,"");
            b = b.replaceFirst(letra,"");
            yaRetiradas.add(letra);
        }
    }
    return a+b;
}
}
```

output string: **adefghi**

Then store in array

```
char array[] = regenerate(a,b).toCharArray();
```